# Programs for generating a character sheet

Tags: character-sheets, tool-recommendation

This is my first question.

I'm looking for a character sheet generator. For example, names, skills, attributes, missions. Dou you know a program (Web or desktop)?

A long time ago I read a question that indicates a program, but I forgot It.

**EDIT:**

I want generate an Medieval RPG game and a Cyberpunk RPG game

Comment: By generator, do you mean a program that enters the data instead of you?

Comment: Can you tell us which RPG system it is you are using please? Without that it is very difficult to answer your question.

Comment: I want generate an Medieval RPG game and a Cyberpunk RPG game

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE, unfortunately this doesn't appear to be a topic we can answer here.  First of all this would wind up being a link graveyard if we can figure out what you'd like to do, and secondly the question appears to be far too vague to be able to answer properly.  Please check out the [How to Ask](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help/on-topic] pages for more information.